# Supabase join with sdk on auth.users() table

Tags: reactjs, supabase

I have this table called `appointments`:

`----------------------------------------------------------------------`
`| id | created`*`at | date | timeslot | user_id (FK on auth.users().id)` 

`----------------------------------------------------------------------`*

And this code:

```
  const fetchAppointments = async () => {
    const { data, error } = await api
      .from("appointments")
      .select(`*, users(*)`);

    if (data && !error) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  };
```

and I want to query also the related `user_id` from the `auth.users()` table.

I've tried searching on google and gpt for solutions with no luck. I have the SQL query working:

```
select
  *
from
  appointments
  join auth.users on appointments.user_id = auth.users.id
```

but not the actual code.

every time I try using as the docs says (the code I've provided here) it says error 400 bad request.
Do you by any chance know what the problem is? I can't seem to find a solution here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pull data from multi tables at once from supabase tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75552011/how-to-pull-data-from-multi-tables-at-once-from-supabase-tables)

Comment: It does not work unfortunately, I'm trying to populate user_id from the table users which is not in public tables, it's in auth.users. can seem to figure out why it's not working as I did everything as I supposed to

Comment: I think this question and answer is related to yours. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75025231/how-to-perform-a-join-in-supabase-with-my-tables

Comment: It’s not related as I’m trying to accesses Auth schema and not public. Can’t seem to figure out how do this

Comment: Is this query not related to yours? `await supabase.from("appointments").select(`*, user_id(*)`).eq("user_id", userId).single();`. And did you read this doc: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/managing-user-data

Comment: It's giving me bad request. I read the docs it says the auth.users in hidden from API but in the JS client docs it says you can accsses it but I don't know how to accsses it via the join in the client.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so what I eventually did is to follow supabase own guidelines regarding `auth.user` approaches,
and created a `profiles` table that mutate the same data that the `auth.users` had, and I was then able to join the data properly inside the client's end from the fetching function.

Pretty bloated approach but I had no way of doing so otherwise.
Thanks for the help for everybody who read the post.
I hope this post help others with related issues as I had.